# Problem with Firebase authentication: Rules and user rights on Node-Red

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am using a firebase to write data from my Node-Red environment to a firebase table.
Authentication is done via a service account with a JSON Key.

I am trying to allow the account only to read and create new entries in the database, but not to delete or update already existing ones.

I used standard rules on the Firestore:

```
  service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create: if true;
      allow delete: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Trying these rules also works fine.
But f I try to do operations with the user I get *"Missing or insufficient permissions."*
If I then grand the user the "Editor" role via IAM, the user is able also to delete entries.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Before investigating further, I would please ask you to answer the following questions:
1. Do you want to allow any user signed in to the application or only the authenticated ones?
2. Which kind of operations (read, write, update, create or delete) cannot you perform with which user?

Comment: Since there is only one technical user - I dont mind if any user or authenticated ones.

The problem is more, that even if I deny delete operation, the user is able to do so.